# Images with psd format in apps

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

In many apps exist images with psd format what are they?

Comment: I guess the developers misplaced them in the project, or is there evidence that they're being used?

Comment: yes they are use them like gif images

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking what the .psd file type is?

If so - it's the Photoshop native format.

Comment: I know what is psd files.  in some apps exist images with psd format that every psd image contain two or more images(like images that exist in gif files) i want to know that how does programmer use them ?